# How do I submit an HTML/JS form to URL 1 but redirect to URL 2

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

I would like to use HTML or JavaScript to create a form that when submitted sends the data to one URL but redirects the browser to another. So the user enters the data in the form, and clicks 'Submit'. Then the form data is sent to https://1111.example.com. After the data is submitted, the browser is redirected to https://2222.example.com. (I do not have control of https://1111.example.com, so I can't put the redirect there.)

How do I do this with HTML or JavaScript with this type of form?:

```
<form action="https://1111.example.com" method="get">
<p><label for="a">a</label><input type="text" name="a" id="a" /></p>
<p><label for="b">b</label><input type="text" name="b" id="b" /><
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Haven't been able to find a solution yet, so I'd appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You can submit form via Ajax and then on successfull response need to redirect second URL (https://2222.example.com)

Comment: You can not let the form submit to the first URL directly then; you will either have to send the form data there via AJAX (for that to work, the remote resource would have to be CORS-enabled), or you will have to submit this to a script on your own server first, send the data to the first target URL via cURL/guzzle/something similar, and then make a server-side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the URL to be fetched then redirect the user depending on the response.

```js
function sleep(lf_ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, lf_ms));
}

async function check_form() {
  console.log('SENDING');
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log('CHECKING RESPONSE');
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://1111.example.com');
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log('RESPONSE OK');
      window.location = 'http://2222.example.com';
    } else {
      console.error("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('IMPOSSIBLE REQUEST:');
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="check_form(); return false;">
<p><label for="a">a</label><input type="text" name="a" id="a" /></p>
<p><label for="b">b</label><input type="text" name="b" id="b" />
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```